# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

The code is :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

run python name.py

return the message

```
File "test_chr.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-64-generic x86_64)
```

my selenium version 
Successfully installed selenium-3.0.2

ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-227:/usr/bin$ chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320)

google-chrome  -version

Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87

I have no idea how to fix the problem

Comment: Are you trying to run this headless?

Comment: I give up . change the firefoxDriver .now all is ok

Comment: driver.close instead work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `--headless` as an argument to start chrome. You can do that by creating a `ChromeOption` object and passing it to `ChromeDriver`.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> chrome_options = Options()
>>> chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
>>> driver.get("https://www.google.com")
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img").get_attribute("alt")
'Google'
```